# How to improve typeahead suggestions in search box

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, typeahead.js, search-box

I am newbie to front-end development. I have implemented search box in one of our old legacy .net application. It is working fine but it needs to be improved.
My search result basically return *'a href'* tag. So users can directly click on it and do their work.

**Issue:**

- Whenever users scroll through the result list, they see actual *'a href'* tag in list.
- Only search result's text part is clickable but not entire highlighted area.
- Somehow *'Enter'* is not working.

**For e.g:**

If I type '*test report*' it shows me correct suggestions, but I can see  tag while scrolling down.

[image]

**What I am looking for:**

- I don't want to see *'a href'* tag while scrolling down the results but only text value inside of it. At the same time I need to retain those tags for clicking on it as it will redirect me to desired result page accordingly.

**For e.g:** in above case I want to see 'Test Report PSC' in text box but at the same time 'Test Report PSC' should be clickable.

- When I hit enter it should behave same as of mouse click.
- Also I want entire area clickable and not only result's text part.

Please point me in correct direction here, thank you.

**Code:** 
HTML file

```
<div class="app-header-icons pull-right">
   <div class="app-header-icon app-search-icon">
      <div class="app-header-search-container">
           <label for="search" class="sr-only">Search</label>
           <input class="typeahead form-control"  id="search" type="search" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Start Searching..."/>
       </div>
       <i class="tem tem-search"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS file

```
 $(document).ready(function () {      

    var substringMatcher = function (reportNames) {
        return function findMatches(inputString, callbackFunc) {
            var matches = [];
            var substrRegex = new RegExp(inputString, "i");
            $.each(reportNames, function (i, reportName) {
                if (substrRegex.test(reportName)) {
                    matches.push({ value: reportName });
                }
            });
            callbackFunc(matches);
        };
    };

    //reportNames is an array
    // reportName[0] = <a href="blah" title="blah"> Actual Value </a>
    var reportNames = getReportSearchLists(); 

    $("#search").typeahead({
        hint: true,
        highlight: true,
        minLength: 3,
        order: "asc"
    },
    {
        name: "reportNames",
        displayKey: "value",
        source: substringMatcher(reportNames)
    }).bind('typeahead:selected', function (obj, datum) {
        $('.typeahead').typeahead('val', '');
    });});
```

Comment: What is the value of `reportNames`?

Comment: @whipdancer I modified my question to show what is there in reportNames

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typeahead will display exactly the values you give it.  In this case, because the value is `<a href="blah" title="blah"> Actual Value </a>` that is exactly what you will see in the suggestion list.

I don't know if you will be able to get all the behavior you are after, but this should point you in the right direction.

Modify `getReportSearchLists()` to return objects instead of strings, such as:

```
[
  { "title":"My Report","url":"/my/url/to/report" },
  { "title":"Other Report","url":"/my/url/to/report" },
  { "title":"Something Report","url":"/my/url/to/report" }
]
```

Update `substringMatcher` to return objects:

```
var substringMatcher = function (reportNames) {
    return function findMatches(inputString, callbackFunc) {
        var matches = [];
        var substrRegex = new RegExp(inputString, "i");
        $.each(reportNames, function (i, obj) {
            if (substrRegex.test(obj.title)) {
                matches.push(obj);
            }
        });
        callbackFunc(matches);
    };
};
```

Use a template to display the suggestion:

```
$('.typeahead').typeahead({
  highlight: true
}, {
  name: 'reports',
  display: 'title',
  source: substringMatcher(reportNames),
  templates: {
    empty: [
      '<div><strong>No match found</strong></div>'
    ].join('\n'),
    suggestion: '<div class="card"><a href="' + obj.url + '"><strong>' + obj.title + '</strong></a></div>')
  }
});
```

Comment: I tried this solutions and it works somewhat. But now it wont show any text in Search box while scrolling down search results.

Comment: I believe that scrolling the suggestions list will not put a value in the input box itself, you still have to select something.

Comment: you can also modify the suggestion html to see what effect that might have

Comment: Sorry your given solution is correct, somehow I forget to change displayKey attribute to 'title' (displayKey: "title",)